# Group RabbitMQ messages by id to processes them synchronously

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm developing a solution that has two application: Only one publisher and Only onde consumer. This customer that needs to process messages like this:

```
2020-09-30T19:22:41 MSG1) {id:'user1.123', msg: '{ANYJSON}'}
2020-09-30T19:22:42 MSG2) {id:'user2.345', msg: '{ANYJSON}'}
2020-09-30T19:22:43 MSG3) {id:'user3.877', msg: '{ANYJSON}'}
2020-09-30T19:22:43 MSG4) {id:'user1.123', msg: '{ANYJSON}'}
2020-09-30T19:22:43 MSG5) {id:'user1.123', msg: '{ANYJSON}'}
```

Each message takes 5-10 seconds do be processed(db queries, 4 http request, db insert e etc.) and I'm creating a pool (https://threads.js.org/usage-pool) for each message because it needs to repeat commands(db queries, 4 http request, db insert e etc.) for many users. So each POOL/MSG can run concurrently.

These IDS are dynamically generated by the publisher and it changes every time. Basically I need to "group" messages by Id and only process messages when there is no message been processing concurrently for this id. For example:

- `MSG 1` (2020-09-30T19:22:41) should be processed immediately
- `MSG 2` (2020-09-30T19:22:42) should be processed immediately
- `MSG 3` (2020-09-30T19:22:43) should be processed immediately
- `MSG 4` (2020-09-30T19:22:43) should wait `MSG 1` be processed
- `MSG 5` (2020-09-30T19:22:43) should wait `MSG 4` be processed

Suppose that after 1 minute consumer receive:

```
2020-09-30T19:23:41 MSG6) {id:'user1.123', msg: '{ANYJSON}'}
2020-09-30T19:23:42 MSG7) {id:'user2.345', msg: '{ANYJSON}'}
```

- `MSG 6` (2020-09-30T19:23:41) should be processed immediately because `MSG5` has already been processed.
- `MSG 7` (2020-09-30T19:23:41) should be processed immediately because `MSG2` has already been processed.

[image]

At line 366 I know when a pool is finished, so its time to ask another MSG for the same id.

So, how could implement this queue "grouped" by id?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: There is no specific feature for this in RabbitMQ.
You might be able to hack it with a topic exchange and a queue per user id. But I wouldn't encourage this.
I recommend you handle this in a storage system or a cache like Redis. If the id of a message is being handled by another thread, park the message in the Cache.